# RFC 1035 Header Structure

Tags: dns, rfc1035

I'm studying about dns and would like to understand about this information, because I could not fully understand.

The header contains the following fields:

```
                                1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    QDCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ANCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    NSCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ARCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

I would to know what mean this numbers on top.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers across the top are simply the bit numbers within the 16 bit word, although as is common with the RFC series of documents they're ordered from *most significant bit* to *least*, instead of the (more intuitive) other way around.

So, for example, given an array `data` of octets containing that header, the ID would be:

```
 (data[0] << 8) | data[1]
```

and the QR bit would be the most significant bit of `data[2]`

Comment: ok so -> `0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5` this is the 16bit word. and about -> `1  1  1  1  1  1` what this is? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The '1's are just the "tens" for the "0 1 2 3 4 5" underneath them, so that they go from 0 .. 15

Comment: and no, I don't know why the RFC author decided to write them vertically instead of horizontally.  Next time I see him, I'll ask.